# Keep Decimal Place When Importing CSV to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm importing a CSV directly into my database via PHPmyadmin. Everything has gone smoothly until I checked a column that has decimal spaces. Instead of keeping the decimal places in tact it simply removed everything after the ', & .'.

I tried removing the separators before uploading and then it just shows the full number i.e. 125657458 and doesn't add in the decimals.

I have set the Datatype to 'DECIMAL' for the column.

Row From CSV:

Ricky   Manager Standard    Normal  156,200

Results with decimal place in-tact on upload:

Ricky   Manager Standard    Normal  156

Results with decimal place not present on upload:

Ricky   Manager Standard    Normal  156200

Comment: Can you please paste a specific before/after example?

Comment: Also, show one row from your CSV.

Comment: Datatype DECIMAL: how many decimal digits have you specified?

Comment: I have specified 2 - in the length / set I have: 10,0

Comment: You should use a period as the decimal separator in your CSV. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/number-literals.html

Comment: I've tried that and it removes everything after the period e.g. this 156.200 is converted to 156

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DECIMAL(10,0) says to round to an integer.  So, 156.200 becomes 156 and 156.9 becomes 160.  Do you have any examples to verify the latter?

I notice you used "," as the decimal point; have you configure things to the call "," a decimal point and "." a 'thousands separator'?  That is not the default.

DECIMAL(10,3) will take in 156.789 exactly.

No datatype will accept input that has a 'thousands separator'.  That is, nothing will correctly accept 123,4567,789.12 (English) or 123.456.789,12 (some European) or 12,34,567.89 (Indian).